# Transient field causing serializeable error

Tags: java, serialization, glassfish, ejb, transient

I have a class that has marked two fields serilizeable

```
@Transient
private List<Edge> edges;

@Transient
private List<Cell> cells;
```

and this works when I get instances of this from the server to my application. Which is an application client. When I try to save an instance of this class back to the server I get serilisation error.

```
WARNING: 00100006: Class pojo.Cell is not Serializable
at beans._MazeBeanRemote_Wrapper.saveMaze(beans/_MazeBeanRemote_Wrapper.java)
```

Can someone tell me why I get this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Maybe your annotations don't work like they are supposed to?

Comment: This is what I think but how do I make them work both ways?

Comment: Try to make them simply `private transient`

Comment: Thanks that did it. It seems that the @Transient annotation only works from server to client and I needed the transient keyword for it to work the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your annotations are not working.

Try to make your fields simply `private transient`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented `Serializable` interface in your class?

And `transient` means that this particular field will not be serialized.

Comment: I haven't implemented serializeable because I don't want these fields to be serializeable. This is why they are marked @Transient but it only seems to work one way.

Comment: In this case you basically should implement Serializable, but mark those fields as transient. So the rest of the fields will be serialized except of `edges` and `cells`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a confusion, there are two kinds of Transient:

`transient` : java keyword to denote a field that will not be serializable

`@Transient` : JPA annotation that indicates that the field will not be persisted

In your case the enclosing class could implement the `Serializable` interface, and mark the fields (and the classes of the fields) with `transient`.